# Proving an equivalent condition for uniform integrability (Proof Verification)

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, analysis, solution-verification

In Chapter 2 of *Probability and Stochatics* by Cinlar, the author gives the following theorem.

> Theorem 3.14. The collection $\mathcal{K}$ is uniformly integrable if and only if it is $L^1$-bounded and for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\delta > 0$ such that, for every event $H$,
> $$ \hspace{3cm} \mathbb{P}(H) \leq \delta \implies \sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{E} |X| 1_H \leq \epsilon. \hspace{3cm} (*) $$

I was not satisfied with the book's proof of the converse direction, as it skimmed over many details. I have attempted to write up the proof in full detail, and I would just like to make sure that my proof is sound and complete. To begin, here are the relevant definitions:

A collection $\mathcal{K}$ of real-valued random variables is said to be:

- *uniformly integrable* if
  $$ \lim_{b \to \infty} \sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{E} |X| 1_{\{|X| > b \}} = 0; $$
- *$L^1$-bounded* if
  $$ \sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{E}|X| < \infty. $$

*My proof* (converse direction)

$(\impliedby)$ Suppose that $\mathcal{K}$ is $L^1$-bounded, and that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for every event $H$, the statement $(*)$ holds. Fix $\epsilon > 0$, and then select a $\delta > 0$ that satisfies this condition. By Markov's inequality,
$$ \mathbb{P}\{|X| > b\} \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}|X|}{b} $$
for all $b \in \mathbb{R}_{+}, \, X \in \mathcal{K}.$ Therefore,
$$ \qquad \sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{P}\{|X| > b\} \leq \frac{1}{b} \sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{E}|X| < \infty \qquad \forall b \in \mathbb{R}_{+}. $$

Now set $b' := \frac{1}{\delta} \sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{E}|X| > 0$. (We can assume  $\sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{E}|X| > 0$, since otherwise $X = 0$ almost surely for each $X \in \mathcal{K}$, and so the claim is trivial.) Then
\begin{align*}
   b \geq b' \implies & b \geq \frac{1}{\delta} \sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{E}|X| \\[3pt]
             \implies & \frac{1}{b} \sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{E}|X| \leq \delta \\[3pt]
             \implies & \sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{P}\{|X| > b \} \leq \delta.       
\end{align*}

Then for each $Y \in \mathcal{K}$, putting $H = \{ |Y| > b\}$ in $(*)$ gives
$$ b \geq b' \implies \mathbb{P} \{|Y| > b \} \leq \delta \underbrace{\implies}_{\text{by } (*)} \sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{E} \left[ |X| 1_{\{|Y| > b \}} \right] \leq \epsilon.  $$

Since the above holds for *all* $Y \in \mathcal{K}$, it follows that
$$ b \geq b' \implies \sup_{Y \in \mathcal{K}} \sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{E} \left[ |X| 1_{\{|Y| > b \}} \right] \leq \epsilon.  $$

Then noting that
$$ \sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{E} \left[ |X| 1_{\{|X| > b \}} \right] \leq \sup_{(X,Y) \in \mathcal{K} \times \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{E} \left[ |X| 1_{\{|Y| > b \}} \right]  $$
for all $b \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$, it follows that
$$ b \geq b' \implies \sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{E} \left[ |X| 1_{\{|X| > b \}} \right] \leq \epsilon. $$

Hence,
$$ \lim_{b \to \infty} \sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{E} \left[ |X| 1_{\{|X| > b \}} \right] \leq \epsilon.  $$
And since $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, we can conclude that
$$ \lim_{b \to \infty} \sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{E} \left[ |X| 1_{\{|X| > b \}} \right] =0,  $$
which is exactly the definition of uniform integrability. $\qquad \square$

Does this proof look okay? The book's proof is more concise (and it uses the notation $k(b) := \sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{E} |X| 1_{\{|X| > b \}}$). The last few sentences read:

> "[Markov's inequality] shows the existence of $b$ such that $\mathbb{P}\{X > b\} \leq \delta$ for all $X$, and then for that $b$ we have $k(b) \leq \epsilon$ in view of $(*)$ used with $H = \{X > b\}$. In other words, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $b < \infty$ such that $k(b) \leq \epsilon$, which is the definition of uniform integrability.

If my understanding is correct, we need to exercise some care when plugging in a set $H$ since $(*)$ holds for each *fixed* event $H$, so the supremum in $(*)$ cannot automatically be taken over an $H$ that depends on $X$, hence the intermediate steps that I included involving $Y$...Do I have this right?

Comment: Your proof look correct. However, as the book mentions (using $L^1$ boundedness) you get $b$ such that $P(|X|>b)\leq \delta$ for all $X$. From $(\ast)$, you get $\mathbb{E}(|X|1_{\{|X|>b\}})\leq \epsilon$ for every $X$. (Note the weaker conclusion we are drawing.) Since the RHS does not depend on $X$, you can take supremum over $X$. In other words, once you have understood the argument, you see that there is no difficulty "when plugging in a set $H$ since...". But if you don't see it immediately, it is best to parse all details as you have so splendidly done!

Comment: @Raghav: Thanks for your comment! I think I get it now--let me try to paraphrase: We can pick $b' \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ such that $P(|X| > b') \leq \delta$ for all $X \in \mathcal{K}$.  By assumption, $P(H) \leq \delta \implies \mathbb{E}[|X| 1_H] \leq \epsilon$ for all events $H$ and all $X \in \mathcal{K}$. Then in particular, $\mathbb{E}[|X| 1_{\{|X| > b'\}}] \leq \epsilon$ for all $X \in \mathcal{K}$. Hence, $\sup_{X \in \mathcal{K}} \mathbb{E}[|X| 1_{\{|X| > b'\}}] \leq \epsilon$, and then the result follows...do I have that right?

Comment: That’s right! One of my professors once said thay a good proof is like a detective novel. You give enough detail so that the reader don’t feel cheated at the end; but hide enough so that the reader is surprised!